# How can I format (bold, underline, etc) a cell with Google Sheets API through NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, formatting

I use googleapis@105 and google-auth-library as dependencies and google sheets "v4", but I haven't the `requests` option on `RequestBody` parameter of the method `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` as many persons show. I'm just able to update a value on a cell or a range of cells but I don't know how to format it. Thank you all for the responses!

As I said, I tried using the `requests` parameter, but it doesn't appear on code or auto-completion and I'm using the right syntax (I used it too many times before with success, but I don't know how to format it)

Comment: Have you read docs for formatting cells?  The key is `{textFormat: {"bold": true}` and so on. [docs here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected result. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal? And also, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?